# Magento 2: Add category dropdown attribute to product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, backend

Is it at all possible to add a category dropdown attribute to a product? I need to somehow select a primary category when adding/editing products. I've seen suggestions to paste in the category's ID, however, this isn't ideal for our site administrators and a simple dropdown would be much more user-friendly.

I've created the custom attribute as a text field (same as category_ids) but I was wondering if there was a way to simply apply the category dropdown to that and populate the field accordingly (wishful thinking, I'm sure).

Comment: have you tried with simple UiComponent multiselect dropdown element?

Comment: I haven't! I'm a bit unsure where to look for a solution because everything I search for is returning custom attributes for categories. I appreciate my question is a bit open-ended but do you have a link to any resources?